# Some divs don't move on page when re-sizing page

Tags: html, css

I have several divs within a container div. Some move flawlessly when re-sizing the page while some not. There is no difference between the ones move and the ones don’t in terms of CSS details and coding in default file. Only the names and values are different.

Anyone to help me out?

DEFAULT file

```
<div id="container">
<div id="logo"><a href="default.aspx" class="cc02">
<img src="logo.png" alt="test" border="0"/></a></div>

<div id="searchbox" >
<form method="post" action="search.aspx" target="_search" >
<table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" onkeypress="   
(txtSearch.value==../MyWebsite/search2.aspx?TextBox1.value)"> 
<tr> 
<td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-
color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;">
<input type="text" name="txtSearch")"  
style="width:140px; border:0px ; height:20px; padding:0px 3px; 
position:relative;"/> 
</td>
<td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 
<input type="button" onclick="search2.aspx" style="border-style: none; 
background: url('searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 
20px;" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</form>
</div>


<div id="Td1"><a href="sale.aspx" target="mainsrc"    
class="cc02">Sale</a></div>

<div id="Td2"><a href="new.aspx" class="cc02">Outwear</a></div>
```

LOGO and SEARCHBOX are moving along the page, while Td1 and Td2 are not moving at all.

CSS

```
div#container 
{width:960px; 
height:820px; 
background:transparent; 
text-align:left; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}


div#logo 
{position:absolute;
top:12px;
width:275px;
height:60px;
left:26px; left:auto;}             

div#searchbox {
background:white;
padding:0px;
width:174px;
position:absolute;
height:24px;
margin-left:400px;
margin-top:10Px;
text-align:left;
top: 22px;} 


div#Td1
{position:absolute;
left:760px;
top:36px;
width:45px;
height:16px;
text-align:center;
border-right:1px solid red;
margin:auto;}

div#Td2
{width:85px; 
position:absolute;
left:790px;
padding-left:5px;
top:36px;
text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Please put this code into a jsFiddle or CodePen or something.

Comment: The links in those divs might not be block - and your whole floating situation might be off ... and you might not notice... put some borders on everything and see what is really happening.

Comment: more than one case in your css: such as left:auto in logo, no absolute left position in your search box (only left marging with all element)........

Comment: First of all you have some errors in your HTML code: name="txtSearch")" doesn't make sense and there is an </a> towards the end that doesn't have a beginning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to move the ones that were previously stable. I replaced the direction values in CSS (i.e top, left etc.) with margin-left, margin-top etc.
All now seem to be working correctly.